# How to split text in a row with css

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I'm having a hard time coding row, I can get to split the text, here is my code so far:

[image: picture]

```css
.partthree {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 90px;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.partthree div {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-family: gotham light;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="partthree">
  <div class="txt1">
    <p>You pick which practice areas you want</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txt2">
    <p>You pick your area by county</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txt3">
    <p>You pick how many leads you want</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - which text are you trying to split? And where's the markup that recreates the issue?

Comment: I just linked the picture

Comment: give a try removing flex-wrap if that is your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex-wrap:wrap;` might be in the way or to be injected via mediaquerie for small screens if needed.

You can tune children layout also with :

- `margin` and `padding`
- `min-width` & `max-width`
- .... or else that suits your needs

```css
.partthree {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 90px;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.partthree div {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;/* flex:1; would make them equal width */
  font-family: gotham light;
  font-size: 23px;
  /* extra ?*/
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  border:solid;
  text-align:center;
}

body {
background:#555
}
p {
  margin:0;
```

```html
<div class="partthree">
  <div class="txt1">
    <p>You pick which practice areas you want</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txt2">
    <p>You pick your area by county</p>
  </div>
  <div class="txt3">
    <p>You pick how many leads you want</p>
  </div>
</div>
```